# Best Practice to find best matching instance in a List C#

Tags: c#, list, matching

For sure very simple question for most of you.
But I am struggling with a solution at the moment.

Imagine you have a list of cats (List) where each cat has a list of babys (Kitten)

```
public class Cat
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public bool Gender { get; set; }
        public List<Kitten> Babys { get; set; }  
    }

public class Kitten
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Age { get; set; }
        public bool Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

now I want to find the Cat that has the most matches for given requirements. It could easily be the case that a cat matches only 2 of 3 requirements. I simple want to find the cat that has the most matches to my requirements.

where my requirements could be:

- Name has to be "Micky"
- Age is 42
- Has a Kitten named "Mini"

My actual solution would be to compare all properties and take the one with the highest count of matching properties. But this is not generic and I am sure there are mutch better ways to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where the cat's in sacks owned by 7 wives on their way to St Ives?

Comment: Have you tried something? What are the "given requirements"? C# already has a generic querying mechanism in LINQ. You can pass any predicate you want in the `Where()` function, group using `GroupBy()` etc

Comment: the requirements could be the name and the age of the cat. I will give LINQ a try... but I am not very familar with it

Comment: When you say 'not generic' why does it need to be ? Are there other types for which you need to do the similar matching comparisons ?

Comment: off-topic comment: why you have 2 classes ?  in RL Kitten is also Cat and also can have babies

Comment: @auburg no I just mean my current solution is very "hardCoded" and would not support adding or deleting properties

Comment: @Selvin because it is just a simplyfied example

Comment: There is no "generic" way. If you had only simple property comparisons, then you could implement some Reflection-based solution. It would work, but it also would be slow. However, you have some "advanced rules" (look into a collection-typed property and perform a search there). You will need to "explain" those rules to the compiler anyway, so you will have to write code or construct expressions dynamically.

Comment: You could make that cat itself give you something like a 'compare score'. Implement a method, that accepts parameters (maybe a Func?) and returns a score representing 'how good' it matches those parameters.

Comment: Try to use expression tree to build a dynamic query in Linq. Please follow the link for details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have no opportunity to test this solution, but you can try this:

Assume that you have a list of cats:

```
var cats = new List<Cat>();
```

Now you have defined what are your criteria:

```
var desiredName = "Micky";
var desiredAge = 42;
var desiredKitten = "Mini";
```

And then you have to get your desired cat:

```
var desiredCat = cats
        .Select(c => new {
            Rating = 
                Convert.ToInt32(c.Age == desiredAge) +       // Here you check first criteria
                Convert.ToInt32(c.Name == desiredName) +     // Check second
                Convert.ToInt32(c.Babys.Count(b => b.Name == desiredKitten) > 0),   // And the third one
            c })
        .OrderByDescending(obj => obj.Rating) // Here you order them by number of matching criteria
        .Select(obj => obj.c) // Then you select only cats from your custom object
        .First(); // And get the first of them
```

Please check if this works for you.
And if you need more specific answer or some edits for me to add.

Comment: first test looks quite good for me! Thanks. I was hopping for a solution that would handle new properties 'automaticly'. If I find a solution for this (next) step I will post it.

Comment: @Locke You can create a list of criteria where one is a generic function that returns 0 or 1 and takes `Cat` as and argument, or something like that, just an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you really will compare 2 ou 3 requirements you can simplify using Linq by:

```
// try to find with 3 requirements
var foundCats = catList.Where(t => t.Name == desiredName && 
                                   t.Age == desiredAge &&
                                   t.Babys.Any(k => k.Name == desiredKitten)
                             ).ToList();

if (foundCats.Any())
{
    // you found the desired cat (or cats)
    return foundCats;
}

// try to find with 2 requirements
foundCats = catList.Where(t => 
    (t.Name == desiredName && t.Age == desiredAge) ||
    (t.Name == desiredName && t.Babys.Any(k => k.Name == desiredKitten)) ||
    (t.Age == desiredAge && t.Babys.Any(k => k.Name == desiredKitten)
).ToList();

if (foundCats.Any())
{
    // you found the desired cat (or cats)
    return foundCats;
}

// try to find with only 1 requirement
foundCats = catList.Where(t => t.Name == desiredName || 
                               t.Age == desiredAge ||
                               t.Babys.Any(k => k.Name == desiredKitten)
                         ).ToList();
return foundCats;
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @CharlesCavalcante I have a solution that looks near to yours, but if there comes a new property... i have to make a thrid predicate and so on, imagine you have 100 properties.. this would be a horror scenario ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So, I see that the problem is you don't know if in any near future you will have more properties, so I will suggest going to the hardway and make reflection, the following is ugly af but you can probably (you will) make it better and hopefully serves you well as guiadance:

```
public static List<Cat> CheckProperties(List<Cat> inCatList, Cat inQueryCat)
{
    Dictionary<Cat, List<PropertyInfo>> dict = new Dictionary<Cat, List<PropertyInfo>>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pI in inQueryCat.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = pI.GetValue(inQueryCat);

        if (value != null)
        {
            var cats = inCatList.Where(cat => cat.GetType().GetProperty(pI.Name).GetValue(cat).Equals(value));

            foreach (Cat cat in cats)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(cat))
                {
                    dict[cat].Add(pI);
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(cat, new List<PropertyInfo>() {pI});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int max = Int32.MinValue;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Cat, List<PropertyInfo>> keyValuePair in dict)
    {
        if (keyValuePair.Value.Count > max)
        {
            max = keyValuePair.Value.Count;
        }
    }

    return dict.Where(pair => pair.Value.Count == max).Select(pair => pair.Key).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is the most generic solution there is (need some edge case improvements):

```
  public class ReflectCmpare
    {
        public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
        public dynamic Value { get; set; }
    }


    public Cat GetBestCat(List<Cat> listOfCats, List<ReflectCmpare> catParamsToCompare, List<ReflectCmpare> kittensParamsToCompare)
    {
        var bestScore = 0;
        var ret = listOfCats[0];
        foreach (var cat in listOfCats)
        {
            var score = catParamsToCompare.Sum(param => param.PropertyInfo.GetValue(cat, null) == param.Value ? 1 : 0);
            foreach (var baby in cat.Babys)
            {
                score+= kittensParamsToCompare.Sum(param => param.PropertyInfo.GetValue(baby, null) == param.Value ? 1 : 0);
            }

            if (score <= bestScore) continue;
            bestScore = score;
            ret = cat;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

You should really think about just doing simple compare function
considering this objects is not dynamic this is the way to go:

```
public Cat GetBestCat(List<Cat> listOfCats, string name , int? age , bool? gender, string race ,string babyName,int? babyAge,bool? babyGender )
    {
        var ret = listOfCats[0];
        var highestScore = 0;
        foreach (var cat in listOfCats)
        {
            var score = 0;
            score += name != null && cat.Name.Equals(name) ? 1 : 0;
            score += age.HasValue && cat.Age.Equals(age.Value) ? 1 : 0;
            score += gender.HasValue && cat.Gender.Equals(gender.Value) ? 1 : 0;
            score += race != null && cat.Race.Equals(race) ? 1 : 0;
            score += name != null && cat.Name.Equals(name) ? 1 : 0;
            score += cat.Babys
                .Where(k => babyName==null || k.Name.Equals(babyName))
                .Where(k => !babyAge.HasValue || k.Age.Equals(babyAge.Value))
                .Any(k => !babyGender.HasValue || k.Gender.Equals(babyGender.Value))?1:0;
            if (score <= highestScore) continue;
            highestScore = score;
            ret = cat;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: The search in the `Babys` collection is hard-coded. What if there will be a new property `List<Cat> Parents` and there will be a new criteria "and parents' names are 'Micky' and 'Felix'"? The solution is not "the most generic" as you state.

Comment: Actually Nekeniehl answer is what you looking for. and much simple than my reflection suggestion.
Just create the inquery cat you desired and compare it using reflection.
Notice that the inquryCat should be a new class with nullable properties.